# The finger print unit is too hot

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I've found out my finger print unit is too hot (hand burns) during ubuntu running.
My platform: ubuntu 16.04, Dell Vostro 3450.
What is the trouble, how to define and fix?

Output:
`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated
Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
    Subsystem: Dell Radeon HD 6630M
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Your computer is too hot, not the sensor.